CSV backslash create issue while procession file data
I am trying to process a CSV file in which one column contains JSON formatted data. In this JSON data, some fields use backslashes, which creates a problem when mapping fields with their values.
Link to download CSV file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ei9KzzIDwUiMcNS_O57URAudsolPTuH/view?usp=sharing
$file_name = 'new_testing.csv';

$file_path = '/var/www/html/'.$file_name;

        $file_content = file_get_contents($file_path);

        $file = new SplFileObject($file_path);
        $file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);

                // Read and skip the headers
        $headers = $file->fgetcsv();

        // Process the data
        $chunkSize = 5000; // Set the desired chunk size
        $loop = 0;

        $chunkData = [];

        while (!$file->eof()) {
            // Read the next chunk of lines
            for ($i = 0; $i < $chunkSize && !$file->eof(); $i++) {
                $line = $file->fgetcsv();
                if ($line) {
                    // Sanitize each field in the line to remove backslashes and double quotes
                    $line = array_map(function ($field) {
                        return str_replace(['\\', '"'], '', $field);
                    }, $line);

                    // Adjust the number of elements in $line to match the number of headers
                    if (count($line) < count($headers)) {
                        // Fill missing values with null or empty strings
                        $line = array_pad($line, count($headers), null);
                    } elseif (count($line) > count($headers)) {
                        // Trim extra values
                        $line = array_slice($line, 0, count($headers));
                    }

                    // Combine headers and line values into an associative array
                    $row = array_combine($headers, $line);
                    $chunkData[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($chunkData);

For the first two rows, I am getting the correct data, but starting from the third row, the "Event Value" column contains JSON data with backslashes, which creates a problem for mapping the keys and values.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Also, please include a small, representative snippet of the data in the question itself. Supplementary links are fine, but a question should, if possible, be self-sufficient.

In PHP there's a function called stripslashes(). Maybe that can help? It's better than what you do now.

You're simply not parsing the CSV correctly. You should set both the "enclosure" and "escape" parameter to a double quote - https://3v4l.org/UiqdF

PHP supports (as a default!) a non-standard CSV format that uses backslashes as escape characters. You have to explicitly disable this behaviour using an empty $escape parameter to fgetcsv, as described by the docs:

An empty string ("") disables the proprietary escape mechanism.

If you use this, your code will give you the JSON field correctly, with no extra sanitisation:
$file->fgetcsv(',', '"', '')

